# Override show segue ( transmition left to right )

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7, segue

I want to override the Show Segue , And change it to be from left to right .

I tried to make a custom segue and it worked pretty well but without the navigation bar

So , I need a segue from left to right and a navigation bar with button  on the top right (to go back) .

My Code

```
    import UIKit

class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue
{
    override func perform()
    {
        let src = self.sourceViewController
        let dst = self.destinationViewController

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-src.view.frame.size.width, 0)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
            animations: {
                dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
            },
            completion: { finished in
                src.presentViewController(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not normal. In this case, you will need to include a `UINavigationBar` (on your destinationViewController in the case that you present as a Modal)l,and add the `UIBarButtomItem` to the right and set to nil the `UIBarButtonItem` on the left. Another option is that you can create a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

Comment: Thanks for your help , and if you are sure this will work , I hope you can write well explained answer .

Comment: Sure. I will try an example and I will post it.